# internet explorer 7 jquery slideshow layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I am working on this site: http://richardthearchitect.com/site/
I just checked it in ie7 and the slideshow is not showing up right.  Instead of only one image showing at a time, all of them are showing up on the page.

Also when I scrolled down it seemed that the menu also scrolled down.

How can i fix these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your script find:
timeout:  5000,

and delete the comma to
timeout:  5000

hope this eliminate js error Expected identifier, string or number and probably your problem with slideshow too.